# Angular 1.x abort promise issue when calls in parallel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing issue with the aborting one promise from multiple promises.Below is snippet

```
//Service
var deferedObject = $q.defer();
var promise = $http.get('/someUrl',{timeout: deferedObject.promise});
var onePromise = promise

var secondPromise = $http.get('/someUrl');

$q.all(['onePromise', 'secondPromise']).then(successResponse, failureResponse);

this.abort  = function () {
  deferredObject.resolve();
  return deferredObject.promise;
}

//Controller

$scope.cancel = function() {
   service.abort().then(success,function (response) {

   });
}
```

If I want to abort the promise it will not get abort If I call both API in *Parallel* but If I make *Serial* call or one call it perfectly works.Am I missing something?